# Is it possible to lift a block from the bottom of the map to the top using pistons?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Can you raise/lower a single block by an arbitrary distance using pistons? Will this work with chests?

Comment: The only problems I forsee with moving a block is that if the distance is too far the necessary chunks wont be loaded, other than that you just need enough redstone and the right gates and delays. I think the chests wont work because when you move them normally, you have to break them.

Comment: @Bravo840 - Chunks are vertical, so no worries there. (Just do a small spiraling contraption)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the number of pistons is no limiting factor, then you could use a piston to push the block up by one meter, then use another to push it across one meter. Repeating this pattern of up-and-then-across, you can effectively pass the block up a series of pistons, one meter at a time. Think of it like a staircase. Standing on top of the pushed block essentially give you an escalator.

If you want to block to go straight up instead, then you could simply use this method in a spiral staircase pattern instead. Standing on the pushed block now essentially gives you an elevator.

This will not work with [chests, furnaces, noteblocks,](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZJr86d2IUo#t=1m50s) [obsidian, bedrock, or any blocks with tile entities](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Piston).

Comment: Basically a conveyor belt... I need to get home soon and try these things.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can have upward- and downward-moving escalators/elevators, and using a sand or gravel pushed block requires half as many pistons for the downward-moving models.

Comment: @Keaanu However, timing with sand/gravel is critical since they will break if you allow the blocks to bounce in the stack..

Answer (score 12):

Regardless of the first part, chests cannot be moved with pistons.

But using this set-up (the painting is a piston) and repeatedly turning on and off the redstone, the glowstone block will move upwards, if pistons have a limit of how much they can push, it will eventually stop. And there is the case of lots of cobblestone as a by-product.

[image: piston lift]

Comment: Ingenious solution! However I'd prefer something reusable

Comment: If this works this would be an awesome way to build high towers quickly. +1 for Brilliance!

Comment: Piston doesn't survive the lava :-(

Comment: As ProSay pointed out in another question, the wiki states that the maximum pushable blocks is 12; http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Pistons

Comment: Okay maybe that's not the best idea, also the water moves too fast and the lava get's cooled rather than making cobbles

Comment: @fredley Water moves before lava so you get water, then lava == cobble stone instead of lava frying things. Saw a video of a self building bridge that used cobblestone generators to supply the materials.

Comment: or maybe we can put a piston above the cobble generator so then the first piston will push 11 cobble and the second piston will push 12 more

Comment: @James [Here's the video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2_MpINsBGg) :D