# How can I make a functioning piston elevator in SMP

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I've recently been trying to build a piston elevator in SMP from bedrock to the surface. However, every design I've tried (some of my own, and some from Youtube) results in me getting stuck in a block part of the way up. Are there any ways to get around this? If it's lag related would slowing the elevator down by adding an extra repeater or two between each level be sufficient?

Comment: [Relevant](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25552/is-it-possible-to-lift-a-block-from-the-bottom-of-the-map-to-the-top-using-piston), if not duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a piston elevator I use the "staircase" design

The way this design works is by pushing you up stairs using pistons.

Here are some pictures of how this works:

**Note:** The first repeater is on 2-delay, and the second is on 1-delay.In the screenshots is different, sorry.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just to double-check, have you used this design **in SMP** and had it work? The designs I've tried so far all work just fine in single player, but not in SMP.

Comment: The screenshots were taken in SMP :)

Comment: Awesome, I'll give it a try.

Comment: This design didn't quite work. However, increasing the delay between each piston from 2 to 4 did the trick. Thanks.